# How to enable console commands in production mode?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I want to use symfony [console command](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html) for cron job.
It's working right in dev enviroment, but if I switch mode to production, I get an error "There are no commands defined in the "cron" namespace. isEnabled() method always returns true.

Comment: This could be an issue with your environment. If you deploy without dev-dependencies, not all commands might be available due to missing packages or bundles that are not registered. Please add more information, e.g. what command are you trying to execute? Can you find the command when running `APP_ENV=prod bin/console list` or `bin/console list --env=prod`? If there are differences in the output between your local machine and the server, how do both environments differ?

Comment: Thx for reply! I created custom console command, as specified in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html). Problem occurs when i change APP_ENV from dev to prod in .env file... I can find it when I run bin/console list --env=dev; but I can not find it when I run bin/console list --env=prod. It's about wrong configuration, I think, but I can't find how to fix this

Comment: Ok. Where is your command stored, is it part of the app in src/ or is it in a bundle? If it's in a bundle, please check the `config/bundles.php` whether it's enabled for all environments or only dev and/or test.

Comment: It's part of src/ (namespace App\Command;)

Comment: Could you add the class to the question? You can skip the contents of the execute method, if it's too long or it contains sensitive information, `configure()` and possibly `__construct()` (if you overwrite it) should be enough.

Comment: @dbrumann apparently it was a bug. I executed the command "composer update" and now everything works ... Thanks for your attention dude!

Comment: @ЕгорСкороходов composer update executes cache:clear, probably just cached on prod.

Comment: @Eakethet I ran "cache:clear --env=prod" before posting a question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it was a bug. After executing the command "composer update" everything works.

Answer (score 0):

The composer update doesn't actually fix this problem, not directly. It was the commands at the end of the update `bin/console cache:clear`